# Stop form from submitting in React Antd Design on press enter key inside FormDecortor Field

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a Decorated form input inside Antd react form , when i press enter key the default form submit validation fires which i do not want. I have given onPressEnter of the input but that is never fired and form submits , so I want to know how to avoid this behaviour in Antd with React.

```
<FormInput
                                        validateTrigger={['onBlur']}
                                        rules={[{
                                            type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                                        }]}
                                        form={form}
                                        inputID={"email"}
                                        onPressEnter={this.onPressEnter}
                                    />


<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log("hello");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `<input />` tag, you can use `onKeyDown` method to prevent default as follows:

```
onKeyDown={(e)=> e.keyCode == 13 ? e.preventDefault(): ''}
```

I have created a working example on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vq4j9nrlxl).

Comment: keyCode is deprecated.

Comment: The issue is that this also disables TextArea onEnter newLine behavior and other things. So sadly this introduces some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

i would also not suggest this solution but wanted to fix something just because keycode is deprecated. You can use key instead.

```
onKeyDown={(e)=> e.key == "Enter" ? e.preventDefault(): ''}
```